# Firebase plugin error 400 Error: invalid_scope into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Firebase plugin is installed on Android studio on my computer. When I click on "Connect to Firebase" button I am getting below error.
Help me out..[image]

Comment: Getting the same error here. Let me know if you sort it out please.

Answer (score 1):

It happens on your bad day, yesterday i tried but nothing happened. When i open Android studio today, it is running fine.

see the screenshots below
It asked for some permissions first and log me in

[image]

Yesterday i checked below line are fine with me from Firebase site[image]

Ports were open.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier today. I waited a bit and it works now. It seems that it was a server error on Google's side and it works now.